# replace a number in a dataframe in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to replace 100 in one of my columns with 0.

I have tried replace() function and it is not giving me the expected results.

```
val df2 = df1.replace("col", 100, 0)
```

I want all rows with 100 in column col to be replaced by 0. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If in scala

```scala
df.withColumn("col", when(col("count") === 100,0).otherwise(col("count"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked. I tried this exact code earlier, but used "==" instead of "===" and that is why it failed.